# MongoDB lookup when foreign field and local field are array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have two collections 'questions' and 'answers'.
**questions** document is like this:

```
      [
        {
          _id: "8326ccbn73487290nc",
          questions: [
           {id: "12345", question: "Test", correct_answer: '0'},
           {id: "123456", question: "Test 2", correct_answer: '1'},
           {id: "1234567", question: "Test 3", correct_answer: '1'},
        ]
       },
       {
          _id: "8326ccbn734872ytruy90nclk",
          questions: [
           {id: "345", question: "Test", correct_answer: '0'},
           {id: "3456", question: "Test 2", correct_answer: '1'},
           {id: "34567", question: "Test 3", correct_answer: '1'},
        ]
       }
     ]
```

**answers** document is like this:

```
{
  id: '327rhrne7fr873',
  user_id: '43757fn574057fnf',
  question_id: '8326ccbn73487290nc',
  answers: [
    { id: '12345', student_answer: '1'},
    { id: '123456', student_answer: '0'},
  ]
}
```

so i want to return something like this:

```
[
    {
        _id: '8326ccbn73487290nc',
        questions: [
          {id: "12345", question: "Test", correct_answer: '0', student_answers: '1'},
          {id: "123456", question: "Test 2", correct_answer: '1', , student_answers: '0'},
          {id: "1234567", question: "Test 3", correct_answer: '1'},
        ]
    },
    {
          _id: "8326ccbn734872ytruy90nclk",
          questions: [
           {id: "345", question: "Test", correct_answer: '0'},
           {id: "3456", question: "Test 2", correct_answer: '1'},
           {id: "34567", question: "Test 3", correct_answer: '1'},
        ]
       }
]
```

Can anyone help me how can i do something like that.

Comment: Is there only one question object in the entire collection?, can a question be in multiple questions objects with different `_id` ?

Comment: There can be multiple questions on the entire collection. No, a question can't be on multiple questions with different _id.

Comment: One more question, can an answer object be matched to 2 question objects?

Comment: No, it can't be matched on two question objects

Comment: Shouldn't it be possible to have multiple answers to a question (from different students)? Or do you focus only one student?

Comment: I want only one answer, because i make get request with user_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's possible to get your desired structure in MongoDB. If you do not need extra aggregation steps, I would suggest to query only the data you need, and do the data mapping in your application layer, because it's much easier and we don't want to put too much work on the database.

However, you can use the following approach to get (close to) your expected output, I have kept the field `student_answer`, from `answers` collection and did not rename it to `student_answers`, you can do the extra steps if needed.

```
db.questions.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "answers",
      let: {
        question_id: "$_id"
      },
      as: "answer",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$question_id",
                    "$$question_id"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$user_id",
                    userId // insert user id variable here
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$answer",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  }, // up until this step, you already got all the data you need. You can stop here and do the extra steps in your application layer
  {
    $set: {
      questions: {
        $map: {
          input: "$questions",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                  {
                    $filter: {
                      input: "$answer.answers",
                      as: "answer",
                      cond: {
                        $eq: [
                          "$$this.id",
                          "$$answer.id"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  0
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "answer" // cleanup by removing temporary field answer
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/beGx6SDh_2B)

Comment: You have done great job. Thank you a lot. I have to solve why i got " "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$set'" ", when i implement it on my code . My structure looks fine, like yours.

Comment: You might be on an older MongoDB version, try `$addFields` instead of `$set` and `{ $project: { answer: false } }` instead of `$unset: "answer"`

Comment: Thank you a lot. This is what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pipeline under the assumption that an answer object is matched to a single question object.

```
db.answers.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "questions",
            let: {answerIds: {$map: {input: "$answers", as: "answer", in: "$$answer.id"}}},
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $gt: [
                                {
                                    $size: {
                                        $filter: {
                                            input: "$questions",
                                            as: "question",
                                            cond: {
                                                $setIsSubset: [["$$question.id"], "$$answerIds"]
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                0
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "questions"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$questions"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: "$questions._id",
            questions: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$questions.questions",
                    as: "question",
                    in: {
                        $mergeObjects: [
                            "$$question",
                            {
                                $ifNull: [
                                    {
                                        $arrayElemAt: [
                                            {
                                                $filter: {
                                                    input: "$answers",
                                                    as: "answer",
                                                    cond: {$eq: ["$$answer.id", "$$question.id"]}
                                                }
                                            }
                                            , 0
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {}
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Sorry Tom, maybe i wasn't clear. What i wanted on my response is the same JSON like on questions document, but only to add 'student_answer' (if have value). That response i want when i call to get all my questions.

Comment: Yes, is the response coming back not the case? did you try it?

Comment: Yes. i try it. I get only that questions that have value on answer collections (in my case i want all questions, and if they don't have value on answer collection), and i don't have correct_answer on my response

Comment: I think that query will be on question collection, not on answers

Comment: Can't one question have multiple answers? multiple students ..? it makes more sense to do it from the answers but in theory you can just reverse the `$lookup` and the rest is pretty much the same.

Comment: Sure it can have multiple answers. But i want to display all questions, not only that question with value on answers. This is where i have stuck now